# Data Migration From SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, sqldatasource, data-migration

I am getting this Attribute Error : 'No Type' objectives has no attribute 'split' when i tried to migrate sql db to mysql db in mysql workbench

these are the Log details :

```
Starting...
Connect to source DBMS...
- Connecting to source...
Connecting to Mssql@sa...
Opening ODBC connection to Driver=sa;DATABASE=;UID=sa;PWD=XXXX...
Connected to Mssql@ 11.0.2100.60
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db_mssql_grt.py", line 147, in connect
    _connections[connection.__id__]["version"] = getServerVersion(connection)
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db_mssql_grt.py", line 174, in getServerVersion
    ver_parts = [ int(part) for part in ver_string.split('.') ] + 4*[ 0 ]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db_mssql_grt.py", line 174, in getServerVersion
    ver_parts = [ int(part) for part in ver_string.split('.') ] + 4*[ 0 ]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries/workbench/wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 65, in run
    self.func()
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/migration_source_selection.py", line 406, in task_connect
    raise e
SystemError: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'"): error calling Python module function DbMssqlRE.getServerVersion
*** ERROR: Error during Connect to source DBMS: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'"): error calling Python module function DbMssqlRE.getServerVersion

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries/workbench/wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 543, in update_status
    task.run()
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries/workbench/wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 80, in run
    raise e
SystemError: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'"): error calling Python module function DbMssqlRE.getServerVersion
*** ERROR: Exception in task 'Connect to source DBMS': SystemError('AttributeError("\'NoneType\' object has no attribute \'split\'"): error calling Python module function DbMssqlRE.getServerVersion',)

Failed
```

---

i tried a solution (given below , taken from the link https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66030&thanks=3&notify=195). but it didn't help. I still get the same error. Please help me.

solution:

// We'll need some help from you to diagnose this one. With a text editor, open the /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/PlugIns/db_mssql_grt.py file
and around line 174 you'll find a line that looks like:
    ver_string = execute_query(connection, "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')").fetchone()[0]

Change that to:

```
ver_string = execute_query(connection, "SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR)").fetchone()[0]
```

Then save and retry. Thanks!  //

Comment: Please execute "SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR)" on MS SQL Server and paste result here.